# React Slick Carousel with Next Js not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, slick.js

I am trying to create a carousel in my nextjs project with slick, it seems the css property are not importing and I don't know why, the same code is working perfectly in a create react project

I was expecting the carousel to work because the same code is working perfectly in a create react project

Comment: Please add an example of your code to your question, in the midle time you can check the next css documentation https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/css-modules
Also leave the version of next that you are using, or if is app direcotry or pages directory.